# Vue: redirect to straight to child, while parent has a param

Tags: redirect, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm learning Vue (on TS) and it seems awesome till this point. At the moment I learn about Vue routing, and have a question which I struggle to find a beautiful answer to.

Let's say, I have a parent route, named User, which gets userId as a param. I also have subpages for this route, which are called Profile and Settings respectively, and are being set in the User's children array:

```
routes: [
      {
            component: User,
            name: 'User'
            path: '/user/:userId',
            children: [
                {
                    component: Profile,
                    name: 'Profile',
                    path: 'profile',
                },
                {
                    component: Settings,
                    path: 'settings',
                    name: 'Settings'
                },
            ],
        }
  ]
```

It's pretty cool that I can redirect from User component to Profile or Settings as simple as

```
public redirectToProfile() {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'Profile'});
}
```

But my question is - may I redirect to user's profile from *outside* of the User component the same way, without concatenating the path string like

```
public redirectToProfile() {
    this.$router.push({ path: 'user/' + userId + '/profile'});
}
```

?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply do it by passing params as well:

```
public redirectToProfile(id: string) {
   this.$router.push({ name: 'Profile', params: {userId:id}});
}
```